# WooCommerce - check if attribute exists and then give variable attribute value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a new attribute for my woocommerce products with the slug 'short-title'. The idea being that I want to override the title on the shop pages with the short title. I have set up a loop with the following:

```
if (get_post_meta($product->id, 'short-code', true)) {
$product_name =  (get_post_meta($product->id, 'short-code', true));
} else {
$product_name =  get_the_title();
}
echo '<div class="product-below"><h4 class="product-name">'.$product_name.'</h4>';
```

But this is not overriding the title when I enter a value in the short title field for a product. I think I need a different function from get_post_meta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try :

```
global $product;
$product_name = $product->get_attribute( 'short-code' );
```

instead of

```
$product_name = get_post_meta($product->id, 'short-code', true)
```

And if it not works for you then please also once confirm the slug for the added attribute that it is `short-code` or `short_code`